# .htaccess - trailing slash breaks redirection

Tags: .htaccess

I have created a stripped framework for a small project I am working on, and everything is going great, except for one small problem.

I have the folder structure like so:

```
root
  - app
    - controller
    - views
    - webroot
      - css
      - js
      - img
      - misc
  - config
  - data
  - lib
```

In the root folder I have a `.htaccess` file which redirects the request to the `webroot` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule     ^$       app/webroot/   [L]
RewriteRule     (.*)    app/webroot/$1  [L]
```

once there, I have another `.htaccess` file which checks if the request is a direct request for an file or folder, if not, it passes to the `index.php` file in the `webroot`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$              index.php?uri=$1        [QSA,L]
```

As I said, it is all working fine but there is one minor problem:

When you request `http://example.com/misc`, it changes the address in the address bar to `http://example.com/app/webroot/misc/`.

When you request `http://example.com/misc/`, this does not happen!

The main point is that for the purpose of the project, people will need to access the files in the 'misc' folder directly, in there there is a `index.html` file which means that people go to `http://example.com/misc` ideally there would be no rewrite of the URL and it would just go to the file. There are reasons for me doing this which are not important to the question so before anybody goes "You shouldn't have your folders set like that" I have tried many different ways of doing it and, for the purpose of the project, this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mod_dir doing its thing, so if it thinks a request is for a directory but missing a trailing slash, it will 301 redirect the browser with the trailing slash. Unfortunately, when this happens in conjunction with an internal URI rewrite, the rewritten URI gets mixed up in the 301 redirect so it gets exposed. You'll have to do a preemptive redirect so that mod_dir doesn't do its thing.

Try adding this before the `app/webroot/` rules

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/webroot%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Fantastic, I was thinking about doing it the other way, adding the slash to the URL but I never even thought of simply stripping the /app/webroot part out!